# Is waitpid() a Unix standard system call?

Tags: unix, standards, system-calls

My Professor is going to correct our Operating Systems final project in a Mac OS and in a Linux. So we should use only Unix standard system calls. I searched for a list with all standard system calls, but I'm not sure if any of the sites I found is truly reliable. Does anybody knows a good site for Unix standard system calls?

The only system call I used in my project that I'm not sure if it is Unix standard, is `waitpid()`. Is it standard?

Comment: `waitpid()` is available on both Mac OS X and Linux (as well as being defined by POSIX for a long time).  It is standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `waitpid()` function is specified by the POSIX standard, which is about close as we can get to a standard for UNIX.

References:

- [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm)
- [`waitpid()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/waitpid.html)